# Validate and allow only Date and hyphens in TextField -- MaskTextInputFormatter doesn't work for manually updating text

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a TextField that has a date filter (dd-mm-yyyy), I managed to create the filter using the dependency `mask_text_input_formatter: ^1.0.6` like so

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '##-##-####');
...
child: TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
  onChanged: (text) {
    //
  },
```

so since I couldn't find a good way to mask the text to be a valid date (e.g. no 31-02-9299), I decided to do it manually in `onChanged` callback and update the text at some point, but just testing with a basic  `_controller.text = "1234";` shows the text `"1234"` and not `"12-34"`.

what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you try providing a regex filter? Like so: 

`var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '##-##-####', filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') });`

Comment: yeah I did that first but it allows any numbers so you can still put 88-99-0000 as input

Comment: And why is that wrong? putting zeros in a number is perfectly normal. If you don't want zeros then try one of the following: A. **For no zeros at all** `var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '##-##-####', filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[1-9]') });` or B. **For prohibiting leading zeros only**  `var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '++-##-####', filter: { "+": RegExp(r'[0-9]'),  "#": RegExp(r'[1-9]') });`

Comment: no I mean the date would be wrong, if you are able to set for example dd/mm/yyyy as 99/02/9182, there is no such thing as a 99 day month

Comment: You can't do this with `mask_text_input_formatter` as it performs comparison char by char. See [this source](https://github.com/siqwin/mask_text_input_formatter/blob/master/lib/mask_text_input_formatter.dart#L133).

You have to do this manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

For your specific use case, here's a solution you can try:

```dart
TextField(
    inputFormatters: [
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$")),
    ],
);
```

### Explanation

You can't validate the text like you want with `mask_text_input_formatter` pub as it [performs comparison char by char](https://github.com/siqwin/mask_text_input_formatter/blob/master/lib/mask_text_input_formatter.dart#L133). So you can only validate each individual char using regex.

To perform manual validation of the text of `TextField` or TextFormField`, then you need to use [TextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html). More specifically using either [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/BlacklistingTextInputFormatter-class.html) or [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html). For another example different from your question, here's [How to restrict two dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531323/how-to-restrict-two-dots-in-flutter/59531639#59531639).

Regex expression is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26972181/10830091), test cases for this particular regex can be found [here](http://regexr.com/39tr1).

### Automatically inserting hyphens

If you want to automatically insert hyphens then you'll need to work within [onChanged](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes). Here's a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665352/10830091) for doing this.

If you're going for this approach, you can validate the text within `onChanged` but you'll also have to reset the recently-changed invalid text with valid one since `onChanged` is called AFTER the text has already been changed. So this is lazy validation unlike [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/BlacklistingTextInputFormatter-class.html) or [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html) which offer eager validation before the text is even modified.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to provide this! it's very helpful!

Comment: Very glad it helped!